# IOS Cordova UserAgent issue with inAppBrowser

Tags: android, ios, cordova, inappbrowser

I would like to change the UserAgent in my Cordova app. In order to do this, I added this preference in the config.xml:

`<preference name="OverrideUserAgent" value="my_preference" />`

It works perfectly on Android, but on IOS when I use the [inAppBrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) plugin my userAgent setting changes and I have this one :

> "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3 like Mac OS X)
>   AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/14E269"

It seems like the InAppBrowser plugin erase my previous settings. Do you know how can I bypass this and keep my userAgent setting? Or how can I set an UserAgent with the InAppBrowser plugin?

Comment: How are you calling InAppBrowser? There is code on the plugin to use OverrideUserAgent, so it should work, but if it doesn't work then should be a bug. Report it on http://issues.cordova.io

Comment: I call the InAppBrowser like that: `cordova.InAppBrowser.open('my_url','_blank');` Then the useragent changes (on IOS, not on Android).